# How do I find and replace text?

Tags: text, batch-file, replace, find

I need to make my batch file replace a setting in "config.ini" for example:

```
color = 1A
```

how can I find and replace *ONLY* the 1A part instead of making another line.

Answer (score 2):

Are you in Unix-like OS? if so, just use the sed command:

```
sed 's/1A/replacedstring/' config.ini
```

For more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Comment: added the third slash  :)

Comment: Would had added `-i` to sed, but edit was to short ;) @user1941370: Be careful with sed and pipes for the write-back. Either use temp-files or `sed -i`